# Panorama of cylindric objects

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I want to get the panorama view of cylindrical objects without using special cameras.

The idea was to get a lot of images from different views, cut the center and join these centers together. But I got bad results.

May be somebody knows the best solution for this purpose? May be it's better recognize from video?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can just stack the images horizontal. Use numpy.hstack for each image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) is a great configurable and agile free cross-platform software to stitch panoramic images. You can definitely use it for your task.

If you want to create your own tool for that purpose, you may find useful to read about [Hugin's toolchain workflow](https://wiki.panotools.org/Hugin_Panorama_Workflow) to know what steps may be needed to achieve nice results.

A possible work flow may be

- Take images.
- Correct projection depending on lense parameters.
- Find and verify control points on image pairs (possible algorithms: SIFT, SURF).
- Geometric optimisation (shift, 3D rotation, etc).
- Photometric optimisation (exposure values, vignetting, white balance).
- Stitch and blend output (cut the centers and join them smoothly together).

You may skip some steps depending on your image capturing conditions. The more similar images are (same camera and cylinder positions, same lighting, etc.) the less image correction you will need.